# How to find text between two markers

Tags: python-3.x

I've got the below string and want to find and then join together everything in between `'^[#n'` and `'$,s)'`. these two markers may occur more than one time in our string. thanks in advance for your help.

```
string="O8d:^[#nI just $,s):<#Rh9f^[#n don't know $,s)>jwU*/#'^[#nhow to write this code $,s){<3f9(f3#"
```

for example,here the output is:
I just don't know how to write this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use re.findall with a lazy quantifier:

```
print("".join(re.findall(r'\^\[#n(.*?)\$,s\)', string)))
```